# Is there a way to build all branches of an multibranch pipeline only into one directory?

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

We have a Unity Project that we build with Jenkins. And you can enable incremental building for those builds. 
That means if I build branch1 ones it takes around 50 min. But if I build a commit to that branch it only takes 15 min.

Now for every new branch, it creates a new folder and the initial build takes around an hour. 
If we would use a normal pipeline it would build every branch into one directory and all of those builds would only take 15 min. but we would lose the overview in Jenkins.

Current State:

`Workspace
   ├── Branch1
   ├── Branch2
   ├── Branch3`

What I want:

`Workspace
   ├── Branch1 | Branch 2 | Branch 3`

Is there a way to build only to one directory for all Branches with a multibranch pipeline and keep the overview in Jenkins?

Comment: Well this depends totally on your Jenkins setup which you didn't share .. I build everything regarding to the same project in the same folder. Why sometimes you don't is that this way you can't build different branches of the same project parallel...

Comment: Well from my understanding every branch in a multibranch pipeline creates a new folder for every branch. 
And I can't find a setting, where you could configure otherwise.

Comment: that's why I don't use a multibranch pipeline at all ;) since Jenkins does this ass you say automatically I don't think there is a way to configure it otherwise

Comment: Ja I would totally agree, but we build so many builds that to only put them in one pipeline would be too messy :/ That's why if there is a workaround to it, it would be the nicest solution. 

Thank you a lot Hugo! 
If I find a solution that is satisfying, I keep the question updated. :)